# Facebook get all user details by id

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to get some user details by id in graph api explorer. I know that i can't search by username, so i found id with http://lookup-id.com/ and when i paste that id in graph api it return me error message

```
"error": {
    "message": "Unsupported get request. Object with ID '*********' does not exist, cannot be loaded due to missing permissions, or does not support this operation. Please read the Graph API documentation at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api",
    "type": "GraphMethodException",
    "code": 100,
    "error_subcode": 33
  }
```

if i paste id for my profile it return me only name as data even if i search for email, photos,...

Does anyone know how can i use these fb api to get user details for any profile and instead of only my profile?

Answer (score 1):

> Does anyone know how can i use these fb api to get user details for any profile

You can’t, that is not possible any more.

Unless a user explicitly authorizes your app and grants it permission to access specific sections of their data, you can not get *anything at all*.

> so i found id with `http://lookup-id.com/`

That will only get you the old, global user id.

User ids are app-scoped by now. And you get the app-scoped user id only when the user logs in to your app.

Answer (score 0):

You will want to check your permissions which are documented here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/v3.0

It is hard to find the exact problem without seeing your code.

Comment: i don't have yet any code, I've just testing it through graph api explorer and when i start getting data then i will make some code